# Добавить prompt к редактированию ввода

Tags: python, python-3.x, консоль, input, unix

Есть код с попыткой реализации приглашения ввода с помощью сдвига, но поведение не соответствует ожиданиям, в добавок оно ломает поведение редактирования. Подскажите, как проще всего реализовать prompt для такого кода редактирования ввода (функцию подсветки убрал для простоты):

```py
import sys, os, tty
 
def command_line():
    tty.setraw(sys.stdin)
    while True: # loop for each line
        prompt = "> "
        offset = len(prompt)
        input = ""
        index = offset
        while True: # loop for each character
            char = ord(sys.stdin.read(1)) # read one char and get char code
            
            if char == 3: # CTRL-C
                return
            elif 32 <= char <= 126:
                input = input[:index] + chr(char) + input[index:]
                index += 1
            elif char in {10, 13}:
                sys.stdout.write("\u001b["+str(len(input)+1)+"D")
                __execute(input)
                input = ""
                index = offset
            elif char == 27:
                next1, next2 = ord(sys.stdin.read(1)), ord(sys.stdin.read(1))
                if next1 == 91:
                    if next2 == 68: # Left
                        index = max(offset, index - 1)
                    elif next2 == 67: # Right
                        index = min(len(input)+offset, index + 1)
                    elif next2 == 72: # Home
                        index = offset
                    elif next2 == 70: # End
                        index = len(input)+offset
                    elif next2 == 51: # Del
                        next4 = ord(sys.stdin.read(1))
                        if next4 == 126:
                            input = input[:index] + input[index+1:]
            elif char == 127: # Backspace
                input = input[:index-1] + input[index:]
                if index > offset: index -= 1
            sys.stdout.write("\u001b["+str(len(input)+1)+"D") # Move all the way left
            sys.stdout.write("\u001b[0K")    # Clear the line
            sys.stdout.write(prompt)
            sys.stdout.write("\u001b["+str(offset+1)+"B")
            sys.stdout.write(input)
            sys.stdout.write("\u001b["+str(len(input)+1)+"D") # Move all the way left again
            if index > offset:
                sys.stdout.write("\u001b[" + str(index) + "C") # Move cursor too index
            sys.stdout.flush()

def __execute(cmd):
    print("\nexecuting: ", cmd)

def main(argv):
    command_line()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv)
```

Comment: @YuriiSpace, имеете ввиду как сниппет сюда добавить? Или на песочницу какую-нибудь загрузить? Там работа с tty и escape-кодами, сомневаюсь, что оно заработает.

Comment: написать свою собственную реализацию того же, что делает, например, библиотека [gnu/readline](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Readline) (к которой имеется и [интерфейс](https://docs.python.org/3/library/readline.html)) — весьма похвально, но, чтобы вам было проще помочь, подготовьте, пожалуйста, [mcve]

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, я знаю про readline и умею в него более менее, но мне нужна независимость от этой библиотеки. Код приведённый выше проблему иллюстрирует, лишнее, вроде подсветки синтаксиса, я убрал. Сейчас уберу вызов функции подстветки и пример станет рабочим (относительно). Проблема, как мне кажется в том, что курсор становится в начале, а не на offset и как это поправить, я пока не понял.